# Intel IO APIC "Established APIC Programming Model"

Tags: x86, intel, interrupt, interrupt-handling, apic

I was reading the Intel Atom® processor Z8000 series: Datasheet, vol. 1. Can be found here https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/332065.

For the IO APIC section, it states the IO APIC features an "Established APIC programming model". Neither volume of the Z8000 series datasheet specify what this is, and I can't find anything that specifies it.

It states there are three registers used to perform indirect writes to the IO APIC's ID, VS and RTE registers. The form of the RTE registers in the IO APIC is not discussed anywhere; I checked both volumes of the datasheet, and the Intel System Architecture Vol. 3. I'm assuming I have to follow the Established APIC programming model?

I've looked at the 82093AA I/O APIC document, https://web.archive.org/web/20161130153145/http://download.intel.com/design/chipsets/datashts/29056601.pdf. This document seems to be used as a source for most of the places that reference the IO APIC.

Does this document function as a defacto standard for the "Established APIC programming model" or is there something more to it?

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/APIC references Intel's SDM vol.3 as well as having useful details itself.

Comment: I've seen the 82093AA I/O APIC document already; it seems to be linked everywhere. My confusion is that the datasheet for the processor I'm looking at (Atom Z8000) doesn't specify what IO APIC it is using. Additionally, the registers that the 82093AA I/O APIC document talks about don't match the ones in the Z8000 datasheet, although they serve the same purpose. (IDX, WDW, EOI) vs (IOREGSEL, IOWIN). This leads me to believe that they are not the same thing. How can I know if they function they same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same, the link you posted is the reference datasheet for IO APICs.
An IO APIC it's little more than a look-up table from the software perspective.  So the specs never changed.

This picture in the Z8000 datasheet

[image: Z8000 IO/APIC MMIO register]

is showing the same functionality as the IO APIC datasheet you linked.

Yes, the different naming is unfortunate but the IO APIC dates back to 1996 and a lot of engineers came and went at Intel meanwhile.
The register offsets match.

Anyway, the Z8000 datasheet describes the registers (I used a picture because I could copy-paste from the PDF):

[image: IO APIC use]

The only new detail is the EOI register.
As [brendan pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72772797/intel-io-apic-established-apic-programming-model/72775450?noredirect=1#comment128546204_72775450) Intel updated the LAPIC interface (note the LAPIC, not the IO APIC interface) with the [x2APIC specification](https://www.naic.edu/%7Ephil/software/intel/318148.pdf).
This includes a Directed EOI feature where the OS configures the LAPIC **not** to send the EOI to any IO APIC. The OS will take care of signaling the EOI to the LAPIC and to the IO APIC of interest.

The Z8000 supports both modes: the LAPIC or the OS writing the EOI to the IO APIC.
The datasheet references the legacy mode where the LAPIC does the writing.

The original IO APIC used a dedicated bus for communication with the LAPIC (the APIC bus).
The software would signal the end of an interrupt through the EOI register in the **LAPIC** (note: not the IO APIC) and this, in turn, would signal the IO APIC.
Since the APIC bus disappeared, this IO APIC implementation has a dedicated MMIO register for EOI.

---

I wonder if this design allows for the IO APIC to be remapped when not using Directed EOI, I don't know how the LAPIC finds where the EOI register is if remapped.
Normally, as far as I understand it, older IO APICs have a dedicated bus (so they don't use MMIO registers for EOIs) while newer IO APICs are either in the uncore or behind a PCH or equivalent (so they use a virtual wire protocol over the uncore bus or DMI for EOIs).
This seems different, it's possible that the SoC translates the EOI message to the appropriate MMIO register by reading the configured base address for the IO APIC.
Actually, this may also apply to IO APICs behind a PCH and in the uncore, so that all recent IO APICs have an MMIO EOI register under the hood.

Comment: Good answer. Once again I'm frustrated by the "implicit required knowledge" that is in a lot of the intel documentation (well, pretty much all silicon documentation). Instead of saying "Established APIC programming model", perhaps they could include a reference to what that is right in the same sentence. I'm really not sure how anybody is supposed to break into this field without traveling back in time and just living it.

Comment: @M.Evers I feel you. The Intel document has degraded over time as they keep spreading with new products. Most of the time their documents are ambiguos and use internal names and codes. It's like they are intended for their employees.

Comment: Around 2008, to support > 256 APIC IDs, Intel introduced an "Intel 64 Architecture x2APIC Specification". This primarily involves local APICs (and virtualization) with no major changes to IO APICs. However it came with a mostly unrelated feature called "directed EOI". The basic idea is that instead of OS telling local APIC to send EOI and local APIC broadcasting EOI everywhere to reach IO APICs, the OS could tell the intended IO APIC itself (and not use the local APIC, and avoid an expensive "broadcast everywhere"). That's what the new EOI register is in Z8000's IO APIC (for direct OS use).

Comment: Thanks @Brendan, I'll update the answer. Still the x2APIC spec doesn't document the EOI register in the IO APIC. And the Z8000 still mentions the LAPIC doing the writing. Maybe it's a mistake in the datasheet.

Comment: @Brendan Ok, it's just that it supports both modes.